# How to replace eclipse's default renderer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a eclipse plugin which implement a new WorkbenchRendererFactory.

```
public class MyRendererFactory extends WorkbenchRendererFactory {
      private MyStackRenderer stackRenderer;

      @Override
      public AbstractPartRenderer getRenderer(MUIElement uiElement, Object parent) {
        if (uiElement instanceof MPartStack) {
          if (stackRenderer == null) {
            stackRenderer = new MyStackRenderer();
            super.initRenderer(stackRenderer);
          }
          return stackRenderer;
        }
        return super.getRenderer(uiElement, parent);
      }
}
```

But I do not know to how to replace the default renderfactory with my new renderfactory.

I tried to register it in the plugin.xml

```
<extension
    id="product"
    name="stacker"
    point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
    <product
        name="com.fakecoder.stackrenderer"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
        <property
            name="appName"
            value="com.fakecoder.stackrenderer">
        </property>
        <property
            name="rendererFactoryUri"
            value="bundleclass://com.fakecoder.stackrenderer/com.fakecoder.stackrenderer.swt.MyRendererFactory">
        </property>
    </product>
</extension>
```

but failed.

How could I change the default render of eclipse in a eclipse plugin?

Comment: That looks like the correct code assuming that this product is actually the product that you are running. So are you running product 'com.fakecoder.stackrenderer.product' in your Run Configuration?

Comment: @greg-449: The run configuration is the default plugin-project's http://imgur.com/xxCmG2V. I do not know what does product means. I copied the plugin.xml configuration from another project.

Comment: You can only set the renderer for an e4 RCP product that you are writing. You cannot override the renderer for standard Eclipse.

Comment: really? I found that the render engine has a factory url argument and google show css could change the renderer class. http://imgur.com/43GCuTN

Comment: Yes but all that must be set in the product configuration for the running product which you cannot do in a separate plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to change the factoryurl manually. I could not install the css editor on eclipse 4.4.

Comment: Also standard Eclipse uses IDEApplication rather than E4Application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72512/discussion-between-jichao-and-greg-449).